# Plot a lineal graph with columns diverging from main column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hello I want to create a lineal graph of this Dataframe

```
A  B  C  D
2  1  5  7
1  4  3  1
```

I would like to know the way to create a line graph with this idea:

```
Using A as Main Colum
```

So I want a resulting line graph with this values

```
A  B  C  D
0  -1 3  5
0  3  2  0
```

The main idea I have is to duplicate the DF and do something like this

```
df2=df
df2["B"]= df2["B"]-df2["A"]
df2["C"]= df2["C"]-df2["A"]
df2["D"]= df2["D"]-df2["A"]
df2["A"]=df2["A"]-df2["A"]

df2.plot()
```

Do you have another way to set this graph faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
df2 = df.sub(df['A'], axis=0)
```

output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  0 -1  3  5
1  0  3  2  0
```